# Spark-shell --master yarn stuck

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, homebrew

I installed Hadoop and Spark via Homebrew

```
$ brew list --versions | grep spark
apache-spark 2.2.0
$ brew list --versions | grep hadoop
hadoop 2.8.1 2.8.2 hdfs
```

where Hadoop 2.8.2 is what I am using.

I followed [this post](https://amodernstory.com/2014/09/23/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-yosemite/) to configure Hadoop. Also, followed [this post](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/Spark/ConfigureSparkJARLocation_2.0.1.html) to configure `spark.yarn.archive` as:

```
spark.yarn.archive                 hdfs://localhost:9000/user/panc25/spark-jars.zip
```

The following are my Hadoop/Spark related environment setting in my `.bash_profile` :

```
# ---------------------
# Hadoop
# ---------------------
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/etc/hadoop/
alias hadoop-start="$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh;$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh"
alias hadoop-stop="$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/stop-yarn.sh;$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/stop-dfs.sh"
# ---------------------
# Apache Spark
# ---------------------
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/../bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH
```

I can successfully start hadoop (hdfa + yarn):

```
$ hadoop-start
17/11/12 17:08:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-panc25-namenode-mbp13mid2017.local.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-panc25-datanode-mbp13mid2017.local.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-panc25-secondarynamenode-mbp13mid2017.local.out
17/11/12 17:08:55 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/logs/yarn-panc25-resourcemanager-mbp13mid2017.local.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2/libexec/logs/yarn-panc25-nodemanager-mbp13mid2017.local.out
$ jps
92723 NameNode
93188 Jps
93051 ResourceManager
93149 NodeManager
92814 DataNode
92926 SecondaryNameNode
```

However, when I start `spark-shell --master yarn` it seems to freeze and I don't know what is going on:

[image]

What is wrong?

BTW, I could visit the SparkUI `http://localhost:4040/`, but all pages are blank.

Comment: Can you access Yarn resource Manager? Via `http://localhost:8088`?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Yes, I can. And it shows that the Spark shell application is accepted.  But the details show that `Diagnostics: [Sun Nov 12 18:22:21 -0500 2017] Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as cluster resource is empty. Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:1024, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:0, vCores:0>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:0, vCores:0>;` Does it matter?

Comment: Looks like your Yarn has 0 cores and 0 memory as resources for some reason. Is the reason why your Spark doesn't start. There is no resources.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Not fixed yet...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue an was caused by the fact that I forgot to append /conf to HADOOP_CONF_DIR env variable (/etc/hadoop/conf).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running spark 2.1 cloudera distribution and specified `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf/:/etc/hive/conf/` . Due to some reason it was getting stuck so I modified it to `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf/` and it worked. Still looking for the root cause !